# spring jpa handling null value in max query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to select a sequence id from the database using this query:

```
@Query("select max(pi.sequence) + 1 from ProductImage pi where pi.product = :product")
    int nextSequenceForProduct(@Param("product")Product product);
```

It works well except when there's no values in the table, it throws some type of null value exception from the JPA code.

Is there a way to handle null values in spring jpa? For example something like this SQL:

```
select ifnull(max(pi.sequence),1) from ....
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `"select case when (pi.sequence is null) then 1 else (max(pi.sequence) + 1) end from ProductImage pi where pi.product = :product"`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use nvl() function and change the query to native query or named native query to avoid the exception

```
@NativeQuery("select nvl(max(pi.sequence),0) + 1 from ProductImage pi where pi.product = :product")
```

Comment: There is no "NVL" in JPQL

Comment: then it is better make the query as native query.